# Nmodbus Tcpclient connection closed on timeout error from modbus enabled device

Tags: c#, tcpclient, modbus

I am using nmodbus library (Downloaded from Google Code) for modbus rtu communication over TCP.

I am using hardware (Converter RS485 to Ethernet) for converting my modbus over RTU request to tcp and vice versa.

If i send the request and modbus device is live everything works fine, but if i send the request and modbus device is not live, than my tcpclient connection get closed automatically, i am expecting it to be remain open and throw time out exception but this is not happening.

i have set the timeout values properly but still no result.

My sample pseudo code is as below

```
using (TcpClient _client = new TcpClient(ipAdd, 1025))
{
_client.NoDelay = true;
ModbusSerialMaster _device = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(tcpObj);
_device.Transport.ReadTimeout = 1000;
_device.Transport.WriteTimeout = 1000;
_device.ReadInputRegisters(meterID, startAdd, register);
}
```

I have verified the functionality of converter and modbus hardware using modbus simulator (Pollscan, modbus poll)

I believe i am making some mistakes in setting up the properties of tcpclient, but not sure what exactly.

Any suggestion, inputs are greatly appreciable.

Comment: So you expect to establish a connection to a non existing device? Isn't it obvious why connection is automatically closed?

Comment: Late to the party. I believe, like me, OP wants the node to keep trying to connect to the offline device, so that when it comes online it will connect.